# error expected primary-expression before ')' token

Tags: c++

14:15: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token and
18:20: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token

here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () 
{
   // local variable declaration:
   int a;
   cout<<"masukkan operasi = "; cin >> a;
   int angka1;
   cout<<"masukkan angka = ";cin >> angka1;
   int angka2;
   cout<<"masukkan angka = ";cin >> angka2;
   if( a == + ) 
   {
      cout <<"Hasil = " << angka1+angka2 <<endl ; //hasil
   } 
   else if( a == * ) 
   {
       cout <<"Hasil = " << angka1*angka2 <<endl ;
   }
}
```

pls help me, i'm new to c++

Comment: Side note: `+` and `*` aren't integers.

Comment: What do you think `if( a == + )` should do? Did you mean `if( a == '+' )`?

Answer (score 0):

`if( a == + )`

In the above line `a` is an integer, but you are trying to read `+` or `*` which are charecters. So first change the line `int a;` to `char a;` . Next change the line `if( a == + )` to `if( a == '+')` . Similarly do it for else case.